# XNA Gamestudio - NPCs get stuck at walls and each other (Visual Basic)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xna, collision-detection

I created NPCs that move that direction you're standing at the moment. If they touch something, they never will move again. I don't have a clue and already wasted like 6 hours searching the fault.
That is my Move-Method:

```vb
Overrides Sub Move()

    Dim actorPosition As Vector2
    Dim spieler As Actor

    For Each obj As Actor In Actor.ActorList
        If TypeOf obj Is Actor And obj.Alive And obj.ObjektTyp = "A"c Then
            actorPosition = obj.position
            spieler = obj
        End If
    Next

    Dim difPos As Vector2 = position - actorPosition
    normaldifpos = difPos
    normaldifpos.Normalize()

    If lastTimeAttack + intervallBetweenAttack1 < Game1.Game1Time Then
        If difPos.Length < range Then
            Select Case ObjektTyp
                Case "Z"c
                    spieler.leben -= stärke
                Case "H"c
                    For Each obj As Objekt In ObjList
                        If TypeOf obj Is Spells Then
                            If obj.ObjektTyp = "Z"c And obj.Alive = False Then
                                obj.position = position
                                obj.richtung = -normaldifpos
                                obj.senderE = Me
                                obj.stärke = stärke
                                obj.Alive = True
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next

            End Select
            lastTimeAttack = Game1.Game1Time
        End If
    End If

    If difPos.Length() < agroRange Then
        If spieler IsNot Nothing And Not collide((normaldifpos + New Vector2(-4, -4) * speed)) Then
            position = position - normaldifpos * speed

        Else

        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

And this my collide method:

```vb
Public Overridable Function collide(vek As Vector2) As Boolean
    Dim extrahitbox As Rectangle
    extrahitbox = Hitbox
    extrahitbox.X += vek.X
    extrahitbox.Y += vek.Y
    For Each obj As Objekt In Objekt.ObjList
        If TypeOf obj Is Spells Or TypeOf obj Is Key Or TypeOf obj Is PowerUP Or TypeOf obj Is Coin Then

        Else
            If extrahitbox.Intersects(obj.Hitbox) Then
                Return True
            End If

        End If

    Next
    For Each Act As Actor In Actor.ActorList
        If Act IsNot Me Then
            If extrahitbox.Intersects(Act.Hitbox) Then
                Return True
            Else

            End If
        End If
    Next

    If extrahitbox.X < 0 Then
        Return True
    ElseIf extrahitbox.Right > 1280 Then
        Return True
    ElseIf extrahitbox.Top < 0 Then
        Return True
    ElseIf extrahitbox.Bottom > 720 Then
        Return True
    End If
End Function
```

I would appreciate help!

Answer (score 0):

From your example it looks object stuck because once when it collide with other object you are not doing any update to `position`. After determing collision you have to calculate how deep object is inside other object and move it back to previous position.

One way is after you determinate collision you simply negate velocity.

```
object.Position -= object.Velocity
object.Velocity = new vector2(0,0)
```

Other way is more accurate as velocity remain same and if your origin is on top-left position. It collision happened, it will position your object right next to other object depend from where collision happened.

```
If obj.Intersect(otherObj) Then
    Dim newPos as new vector2d = obj.Position
    if (obj.velocity.x>0) then newPos.x = otherObj.Left - obj.width
    if (obj.velocity.x<0) then newPos.x = otherObj.right
    obj.Position = newPos
End If
```

So basicly goes like this

1. put position to temp varialbe
2. check collision
3. if collision happened set original to temp
4. draw

Comment: Thanks for the help, i tried your idea.. Now he's porting always to different sides.. i have a top and a bottom too.. and i don't have any ideas... And if I am standing still and he tries to go through the wall he just stutters.